# Changing the working directory when using the exec function in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I am executing a command in Rascal on Windows 10 (some batch file) which in itself works fine:

```
import util::ShellExec;
exec("somecommand.bat");
```

This batch file does some file reads and writes in the current working directory. Through some debugging I have found that the default working directory (`|cwd:///|`) is `C:\Program Files\Eclipse` and this directory requires elevated rights to be able to write in it. I am trying to change the working directory when executing the command like so:

```
exec("somecommand.bat", |tmp:///|);
```

I have tried many variations of directories, but they all produce a CallFailed error without much detail.

How can I execute a command in a different working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working dir parameters is a so called "keyword parameter" which you call using this syntax:

```
exec(command, workingDir=|file:///myworkingdir|)
```

Comment: I had not seen these type of parameters before, good to know. Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for asking anyway. Have a nice day